# Cannot get initialAdminPassword for jenkins on heroku

Tags: bash, heroku, jenkins

I am trying to get started with jenkins on heroku but I came across a problem is that now after deloying jenkins to heroku it wants to get the administrator password, and shows me this path `/app/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

I ssh'd into my heroku app and tried cat ( path ) but it shows there is no path like that on my heroku bash.

To set up my heroku server I followed this https://gist.github.com/jordansissel/2313443

I attached a picture of me trying in different ways
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can log out and then write`heroku logs --app yourappname`
The password can be found there on the logs. If you cant see it, then restart the dynos.